# datetime:: diff not working in codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I wrote a php function in my codeigniter view to calculate the age from Date of Birth. It worked with WAMP SERVER 2.4 (PHP 5.4), but showing error in WAMP SERVER 2.0 (PHP 5.2).
My code,

```
function dob($dob)
{
  $bday = new DateTime($dob);
  $today = new DateTime('2013-11-08'); // for testing purposes
  $bday = $today->diff($bday);
  return $bday->y.' Years';
}
```

The error that appears,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in C:\wamp\www\lamsapp\application\views\dm\form_tapal_app.php on line 80
```

Can someone help me out please..

Answer (score 4):

That is because  `DateTime::diff()` is available from PHP ver >= 5.3.0

[**`Source`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 1):

The `diff` should use php 5 >= 5.3.0.

You can referece [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)